# Add filter to wordpress query

Tags: php, filtering, meta-tags

My issue is as follows;
I have fields with no value showing on my page - I want them to be hidden, until they have a value. In my code I have a `meta_value_num` as a sorting option per today. But it still shows values that are 0(zero) and blanks.

Please tell me how I can filter these so that the empty ones are not shown. E.g. if I can sort everything with a value = 100 and above, that would be good enough.

This is how the code looks per today:

```
$tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$new_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'clinic',
    'meta_key' => $treatment,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DSC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field'    => 'ID',
            'terms'    => $tax->term_id
             )
        ),
));
```

Comment: If you want to exclude items, that is _filtering_, not _sorting_. How to filter by meta values: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up. I followed your link and found the right solution.

Big up to you myman!

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the filter issue.

By adding this code it now filters out everything below 20 and shows all above. Big shout out to @Cbroe for pointing me in the right direction!

'meta_value'   => '20',
'meta_compare' => '>=',

Code now looks like this;

```
$tax = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$new_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'clinic',
    'meta_key' => $treatment,
    'meta_value'   => '20',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'location',
            'field'    => 'ID',
            'terms'    => $tax->term_id
             )
        ),
));
```